# Parse Cloud Code vs Parse mobile SDK

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Just a quick question, it says in the docs

```
"Cloud Code is easy to use because it's built on the same JavaScript SDK 
that powers thousands of apps. The only difference is that this code 
runs in the Parse Cloud rather than running on a mobile device."
```

So does that mean it's necessary to also use Cloud Code for server side authentication such as logging in users? Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

I'm also creating a web app for my mobile app but there's a Javascript SDK which has its own authentication but Cloud Code seems to run on the server side so I'm just a bit confused at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use Cloud cloud for authentication. Cloud code can be used for automated calls and jobs that could otherwise not be done or would be very difficult to do.